# Is there any way to use Puppeteer to browse dashboards?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a crawler to consume information from dashboard like this:
https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/dashboards/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const casesSelector = "body > div > div > div > div.flex-fluid.flex-horizontal.position-relative.overflow-hidden > div > div > div > margin-container > full-container > div:nth-child(2) > margin-container > full-container > div > div > div > div.responsive-text.flex-vertical.flex-fix.allow-shrink.indicator-center-text > svg > g.responsive-text-label > text";

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/dashboards/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6');
  await page.waitForSelector(casesSelector);

  const cases = await page.evaluate((cases) => document.querySelector(cases).innerHTML, casesSelector);
  
  console.log(cases);

  await page.screenshot({ path: 'testing-covid.png' });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

But I got "Error: failed to find element matching selector".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why don't you use the API used by the dashboard directly?

Comment: This is an example for learning, not all web dashboards have a public API. The purpose of this is to understand how to consume a dashboard, not specifically THIS DATA, from that dashboard.

Comment: All websites are different, with different CSS selectors and markup structures, so there's no way to write a single script that scrapes arbitrary dashboards. In fact, there's nothing special about it being a _dashboard_ per se; Puppeteer doesn't know what that means -- it's all just a tree of HTML and JS that modifies the HTML as far as it knows. What are you really trying to achieve? What data do you need here?

Comment: Good explanation. I'm trying to get the number of cases for this dynamic loading panel with Puppeteer (it could be any other scraping tool). But I want to learn how to be able to use a scraping tool to handle panels that load dynamically (achieve), it doesn't just depend on the selectors, as well as the number of cases on that panel.